# Unable to send_keys to webelement covered by tool-tip

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I try to fill price to the input element.
I have tried many ways but they are failed and I realized that it may be covered by another element.
While I move my mouse point to the field, it shows a tooltip automatically. And I also see some HTML code lines appears in the inspection box.

Picture1: my screen when I do not point my mouse to that field.

[image: i]

Picture 2: my screen when I move the mouse point to that field

[image: i]

And here are some of my attempts:

```py
price=browserdriver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='inputProductPrice']")
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].innerHTML = "100000";', price)
```

Result: do nothing without error

or

```py
price=browserdriver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='inputProductPrice']")
browserdriver.execute_script("$(arguments[0]).click();", price)
price.send_keys("10000")
```

or

```py
price=WebDriverWait(browserdriver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@id='inputProductPrice']")))
price.click()
price.send_keys("10000")
```

or

```py
price=browserdriver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='inputProductPrice']")
price.click()
price.send_keys("10000")
```

or

```py
price=browserdriver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='inputProductPrice']")
actions.move_to_element(price).click(price).perform()
price.send_keys("10000")
```

I am sure that the XPath is proper and that element is on screen because I can send_keys to the similar field in that row (the field named "2" with blue highlight box in Picture 1).

html:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nhập giá" id="inputProductPrice" title="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="(Trên 8.000 VNĐ)" data-bind="moneyMask: ProductPriceForAll">
                        </div>
```

Pls, help me to overcome this constraint. Thanks

Added words: some fields above this field also have the some tool-tip structure but I can fill in easily and successfully by some of above solutions. But I do not know why this field becomes a strong constraint. For example this field (blue highlight box):
[image: picture 3]

Comment: You should try waiting for the tooltip element to be invisible. Something like `new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).unitl(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocatedBy("tooltip locator"))`

Comment: Have you tried the first one, but setting the element's `value` instead of `innerHTML`?

Comment: @DustInCompetent I tried it but it has the same result. No error notification in console output but nothing to be filled in that field.

Comment: @MateMrše It does not work. Btw, when I browse that page manually, that tool-tip does not disappear until I move my mouse out of that relevant field. That tool-tip does not fade out automatically after a defined amount of time as other common tool-tip hints

Answer (score 0):

You should try using [`ActionChains`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html) and [`move_to_element_with_offset`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.move_to_element_with_offset):

```
action = ActionChains(browserdriver)
price = WebDriverWait(browserdriver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@id='inputProductPrice']")))
action.move_to_element_with_offset(price, 5, 5)
action.click().perform()
```

You can play with the offset to find the area that is clickable...

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unforturnately, it does not work. Get error at line 2, with notification like this:raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why `send_keys("100000")` is not working.However if you are using JS executor try to update `placeholder` or `value` attribute.

```
price=browserdriver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='inputProductPrice']")
browserdriver.execute_script('arguments[0].placeholder = "100000";', price)
```

Or

```
price=browserdriver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='inputProductPrice']")
browserdriver.execute_script('arguments[0].value = "100000";', price)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggest! But it still does not work. When using execute_script, it does not get any error in console output but there is nothing to be filled in such field.